# Visual Studio пропала подсказка console.log

Tags: visual-studio, консоль, visual-studio-code

[image: Пропала подсказка console.log после обновление visual studio code. Она то ли появляется то ли нет подсказали самому сделать snippet. Сделал тоже самое то ли появляется то ли нет. Работает нормально только если как префикс добавить " " пробел. Подскажите пожалуйста что сделать]

[image]
Пропала подсказка console.log после обновление visual studio code. Она то ли появляется то ли нет подсказали самому сделать snippet. Сделал тоже самое то ли появляется то ли нет. Работает нормально только если как префикс добавить " " пробел. Подскажите пожалуйста что сделать

Comment: У меня тоже проблема со своими сниппетами, один раз срабатывает и больше не отображается. Скорее всего какая-то ошибка с обновлением.

Comment: как планируешь исправить?)

Comment: Ждать обновление

Comment: когда она планируется?

Comment: У меня вылезло обновление, проблема вроде решена, проверите?

Comment: спасибо большое у меня тоже